# WPF window ownership is broken at the 50s window

Tags: c#, wpf, z-index, owner

I am spending a few days to solve my issue and I hope that someone of you encountered this thing.

In order to implement a chain of windows by WPF to be ordered by z-index, I tried to make each window as an owner of the next window in the hierarchy.

So it works fine but I have noticed that in the 50's window the chain is "cleaning" and the chain starts over.

all of the 1-50 first windows are ordered by the z-index order and can never over each its parents, but the next, the 51s is starting a new chain and all of its children can over the previous 50.

I would like to get any help in here. didn't find any clue over the internet.

Thanks,

Comment: Don't you think having 49 windows under a window is a design issue in itself?

Comment: no, my product is configured to support alot of windows.
I think you missunderstood. not all of the windows are children of the same window. each window has a another parent by chain.

Comment: I'm not questioning if it can support it or not. But, having lots of windows open, seems a bad UI design to me. May be it works for your case!

Comment: This is a client tool which shows you guide balloon to help you by walkthrough. it's an existing system in production. assume that you have 60 balloon in the same time and you don't want that the previous balloon will come over the new one. the window are very cheap.

Comment: Just because something is existing and in production doesn't mean it is designed well. It seems you are using windows instead of using controls or sprites?

Comment: My client must use WPF technology and I can't use usercontrol because I need container to differ between the ui elements. thanks you all for your response, but the design is fixed and should work. the problem is something in the os. from some reason, only the 50s window causes to this issue. and instead of changing design I would like to understand what the problem is.

Comment: I think it's limit of windows kernel itself: https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/oldnewthing/20031218-00/?p=41453

Comment: Why don't you change window to panel or some other control which supports z-index?

Comment: thanks.
Because I need to show the balloons over the screen and over other application.

Comment: I'm not sure how exactly your application work, but IMO you might be able to get away with just using panels. May be if you post your code/screenshot someone might e able to help you out.

Comment: I can't escape from this design. I have to support a lot of windows and I need to run my app on citrix (xen app) so I can't use a transparent window with user controls because citrix can't support transparancy.